# select statement in hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria-api

I want to make the below query in hibernate criteria

SELECT * FROM ORDERS O, PRODUCT P WHERE O.ORDER_ID=P.ORDER_ID and order.orderName='xyz';

thanks for your help

Comment: [Start here](http://www.google.com/search?aq=1&oq=hibernate%20criteria&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=hibernate%20criteria%20api#hl=nl&pq=hibernate%20criteria%20api&xhr=t&q=hibernate%20criteria%20tutorial&cp=20&pf=p&sclient=psy&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=hibernate%20criteria%20t&pbx=1&fp=1&bs=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&cad=b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below:

```
List orders = sess.createCriteria(Order.class)
    .createCriteria("products", "product")
        .add( Restrictions.eq("orderName", "xyz") )
    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)
    .list();
```

Hope that helps.